How can I disable org-element-cache?
I tried using (setq org-element-use-cache nil), but I'm still getting various org-element-cache-related errors like "org-element--cache: Org parser error...".
What is the proper way of disabling the org-element cache?

That is the proper way. Please submit bug reports (M-x org-submit-bug-report) for any problems you encounter. There was a recent request by one of the Emacs maintainers to document this, so any problems you report will directly help that effort. Thanks!
